# How to update facebook access token in android without logging in again?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

The issue is like this
User log in to my app and give read permissions by doing so. The code used for this is

```
public void onClickLogin() {
        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS);
}
```

Now next time I have put a button to share the app on facebook timeline. For that I have used this code.

```
public void publishStory() {

        Set<String> permissions = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getPermissions();

        final List<String> PUBLISH_PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");
        if (!isSubsetOf(PUBLISH_PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
            Log.d(FBTAG,"facebook publish permission login");
            pendingPublishReauthorization = true;
            LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(this, PUBLISH_PERMISSIONS);
            return;
        }

        ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
        .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://developers.facebook.com"))
        .setContentTitle("My message ")
        .build();

        ShareApi.share(content, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Result result) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.d(FBTAG,"Facebook post id is "+result.getPostId());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.d(FBTAG,"Facebook share cancelled");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.d(FBTAG,"Facebook error during sharing: "+error.getMessage());

            }
    }
```

So now I have the publishing permissions as well.

Now the use case is if the user removes the publishing permission from the app on web. This function checks for the permission on device which still shows both the permissions granted (publish, read) hence try to share the story and then gets the error of permission needed. 
So the issue is AccessToken is saved in cache as SharedPreferences in android and still holds both the permissions while user actually updated permissions granted by him. 
Is there any way to update the access token as well?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [AccessTokenTracker](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.3#track_token) to update current token, if it has changed. Try in listener:

```
         @Override
         protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(
                 AccessToken oldAccessToken,
                 AccessToken currentAccessToken) {
             AccessToken.setCurrentAccessToken(currentAccessToken); //update current token manually, from listener.
         }
```

Comment: Please, look at this tutorial - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.3#track_token This code you should place in onCreate activity method.

Comment: Tried doing that. But my app still don't have the updated permissions. I have put this log in the above code 
Log.d(FBTAG,"current facebook access token permissions are "+currentAccessToken.getPermissions()); and getting this. 

04-02 18:17:07.058: D/fb(7130): current facebook access token permissions are [public_profile, publish_actions]

Comment: Try to look at this [too](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.3#handling).

If I understand you right, it is a very small chance, that user manually remove permission from WEB. Even if it happens, the Facebook SDK, when it doing request to the server, will check token, and if it not have required permission, it must show some error, or permission dialog. I haven't find any SDK references to manually update token from cache - SDK, probably, do it automatically.

Comment: that's exactly what I am getting. So currently what I have done is manually asking user to sign in with the right permissions in case I receive the authorisation error. But still hoping to find a better solution.

Comment: AFAIK, this is only one, and correct (according to FB permission politics) solution. User should manually choose, if he wants to grant it, or not. You can't get permission without asking for it. So it's the only way.

Comment: yes, this is the way, it sucks, but you need to use this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.3#track_token